# Is it possible to access HEIF 'Image Properties' metadata like 'ispe' and 'colr' using Windows Imaging Component?

Tags: c++, image, wic, heif, heic

I know from the [format specifications](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c066067_ISO_IEC_23008-12_2017.zip) that HEIF files have Image Properties that can denote spacial extent ('ispe'), color information ('colr'), pixel information ('pixi'), etc.

**Is it possible to directly access those properties using WIC?**

I am able to access EXIF and IFD metadata tags (if they are present in the file) using [GetMetadataByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicmetadataqueryreader-getmetadatabyname), and to get at the [size info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmapsource-getsize) and [pixel format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmapsource-getpixelformat) by [getting the frame out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmapdecoder-getframe), but I am not sure if there is any way to use WIC to explicitely read out these "Descriptive Item Properties" as defined by HEIF format.

Comment: Do you have an example image that has those metadata for sure? Note it depends from the wic HEIF decoder component. You can install a 3rd party wic HEIF decoder that could do it, independently from what Windows provides out-of-the-box

Comment: Reading the specs I was assuming all images are supposed to have these, but you are right - looks like only 'ispe' is mandatory.

Yeah it definitely is starting to look like these properties are too HEIF-specific to be explicitely accessible by WIC.

Comment: Check out WICExplorer, which is from the WIC team at Microsoft, to see if WIC can do this. If WICExplorer can do it, then so can you. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Imaging-Component-6cfa1857